# vb 2010 Add data to two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm have a 2D array were I collect 10 samples (integers) from 10 channels (integers). I can loop through and average the samples per channel. I need to know how to take the data from current 2D array and populate a second 2D array. Here's what I have so far... thanks!

```
      Dim data(,) As Double = reader.ReadMultiSample(10)
    Dim avgdata(,) As Double
    Dim average As Double

    For channel = data.GetLowerBound(0) To data.GetUpperBound(0)
        For samples = 0 To data.GetUpperBound(1)
            average = (data(channel, samples) + average) / samples
        Next
        avgdata.(channel, average)      'This is where I need avgdata(,) to populate new values from data(,)
    Next
```

Here is sample data... data(0,0) to data(0,4) are averaged and become avgdata(0,0). I am sampling a couple thousand data points and an worried loops will be very slow for 10 channels (20,000 data points). Is there a function to average "inside" an array?

```
   data(,)                          avgdata(,)
   (0,0) = 1.3975149129757121   (0,0)=1.39802466576101
   (0,1) = 1.3975149129757121   (1,0)=1.39827949635731
   (0,2) = 1.3924173851227089   
   (0,3) = 1.3975149129757121   
   (0,4) = 1.4051612047552133   
   (1,0) = 1.3967501822575024   
   (1,1) = 1.4018478959235345   
   (1,2) = 1.3967501822575024   
   (1,3) = 1.3967501822575024   
   (1,4) = 1.3992990390905184
```

Comment: why do you think you need 2 dimensional array (instead of 1) to store average per channel data?

Comment: I am going to display in to a datagridview and later export to excel for plotting. 2D Array will give me column & row locations.

Comment: Then I don't understand clearly what should be the value of each cell in the `avgdata` array. Could you post sample data for `data(,)` and `avgdata(,)`? Array size could be smaller for the sample (no need to be actual (10,10) array)

Comment: data(,)                         avgdata(,)
(0,0) = 1.3975149129757121 (0,0)=1.39802466576101
(0,1) = 1.3975149129757121 (1,0)=1.39827949635731
(0,2) = 1.3924173851227089 
(0,3) = 1.3975149129757121 
(0,4) = 1.4051612047552133 
(1,0) = 1.3967501822575024 
(1,1) = 1.4018478959235345 
(1,2) = 1.3967501822575024 
(1,3) = 1.3967501822575024 
(1,4) = 1.3992990390905184 
Each of 5 data sets is averaged in to new array

Comment: edit your question and post the data there in proper formatting. It is hard to read and understand in comment without formatting. I tried but still didn't get what those series of data means, and what is the pattern ((0,0), (0,0), then (0,1)... what's that mean?)